# Sending command line path to npm run script

Tags: typescript, migration, typeorm, seed

I have script tag db:create which stands for npm run typorm migration:generate src/common/db/migration

I want to attach strings to this npm run db:create command can you help me

Currently I'm giving manually like
"db:create":"npm run migration:generate src/common/db/migration/nameofmigratin"